# PHP How to search for duplicates on a file.txt before inserting data

Tags: php, file, duplicates

So basically, I have a code that I wrote, and it is connected with an HTML form.
And when the user submits the form, my php code already checks it for errors and validates it, and then inserts all into a file.txt in the same directory, all ok with that.

What I need to do now, and I have no idea how, is how can I, with php, check the file for duplicates before inserting the data into the file, so that if it is duplicate, it gives error to the user and does not insert to the file.

I searched everywhere for this, but the only thing I seem to find is how to do this with MySQL, and I need to do this with a .txt file, is it possible?

This is the code I currently have:

```
    <?php   $username = ""; $ip = ""; $port = ""; $usernameErr = ""; $ipErr = ""; $portErr = ""; $readytosend1 = ""; $readytosend2 = ""; $readytosend3 = "";?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    } else {

    function test_input($data)
    {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

      if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $usernameErr = "This field is required";
        $readytosend1 = "no";
      } else {
        $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
        $readytosend1 = "yes";
      }
    }


    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

      if (empty($_POST["ip"])) {
        $ipErr = "This field is required";
        $readytosend2 = "no";
      } else {
        $ip = test_input($_POST["ip"]);
        if(!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE)){
            $ipErr = "The ip you entered is invalid";
            $readytosend2 = "no";
        } else {
            $ipErr = "";
            $readytosend2 = "yes";
        }
      }
    }

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

      if (empty($_POST["port"])) {
        $portErr = "This field is required";
        $readytosend3 = "no";
      } else {
        $port = test_input($_POST["port"]);
        if($port > 1024 && $port < 65535){
            $portErr = "";
            $readytosend3 = "yes";
        } else {
            $portErr = "The port you entered is invalid";
            $readytosend3 = "no";
        }
      }
    }
    if($readytosend1 == "yes" && $readytosend2 == "yes" && $readytosend3 == "yes"){ 
    $file = fopen("file.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = $username ." : ". $ip ." : ". $port ."\n\n";
    fwrite($file, $txt);
    fclose($file);
    }
    }
    ?> 

    <div align="center">
        <form id="orderform" method="post">
            <input type="text" value="" style="margin-top:5px;" placeholder="Username" name="username"><br><span id="error1" class="error"><?php echo $usernameErr;?></span><br>
            <input type="text" value="" style="margin-top:5px;" placeholder="IP" name="ip"><br><span id="error2" class="error"><?php echo $ipErr;?></span><br>
            <input type="text" value="" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:10px;" placeholder="Port" name="port"><br><span id="error3" class="error"><?php echo $portErr;?>        </span><br>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
        </form>
    </div>
```

PS: Using MySQL is not an option.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**try this:**

```
if($readytosend1 == "yes" && $readytosend2 == "yes" && $readytosend3 == "yes"){
    //exist check & insert part 
        $fd=@explode("\n",@file_get_contents("data.txt"));   // read file
        $txt = $username ." : ". $ip ." : ". $port ;
        if(!in_array($txt,$fd)){
            $fd[]=$txt;
            @file_put_contents("data.txt",@implode("\n",$fd));  //  insert
        }
        else{
            echo "data exist";
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to open the file up and go line by line through it. Check each line against the string you're looking for. If you find it, flag that and break out of the loop. Then you can either write to the file or you can display an error message.

```
    if($readytosend1 == "yes" && $readytosend2 == "yes" && $readytosend3 == "yes"){
        $txt = $username ." : ". $ip ." : ". $port ."\n\n";
        $lines = file('file.txt');
        $match = false;

        foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
            if($line === $txt) {
                $match = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!$match) {
            $file = fopen("file.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
            fwrite($file, $txt);
            fclose($file);
        } else {
            // record already exists, do something with an error message
        }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Tried to do that, code was right, and logically it seemed like it would work, but the data was still inserted even though there were multiple duplicates...

Comment: I'd make a test case where you know the line will match and then var_dump both of them. See what they look like.

Comment: I always use PHP_EOL on the end of my entries. I would consider how each data line ends, and change..  `code`if ( trim($line) === $txt ) {`code`